# "Failed to import docker or docker-py - cannot import name constants" when installing AWX on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-awx

I'm trying to follow this :
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-ansible-awx-with-nginx-reverse-proxy-on-ubuntu-1804/

to install  AWX on ubuntu 19.04 by runnng the playbook and i'm having import error .

i try : 
pip uninstall docker-py 
pip unsintall docker-compose 
pip install docker-compose=1.9.0

also try

pip install constant

Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import constants

i had this warning when installing docker-compose :

Installing collected packages: docker-py, docker-compose
  The script docker-compose is installed in '/home/user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed docker-compose-1.9.0 docker-py-1.10.6

TASK [local_docker : Start the containers] ******************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import docker or docker-py - cannot import name constants. Try `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6)"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/awx/installer/install.retry

The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_docker_service_payload_Qt5pEa/**main**.py", line 457, in 
    from compose.cli.command import project_from_options
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 11, in 
    from . import errors
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/errors.py", line 10, in 
    from docker.errors import APIError
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/**init**.py", line 6, in 
    from .client import Client, AutoVersionClient, from_env # flake8: noqa
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 11, in 
    from . import api
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/**init**.py", line 2, in 
    from .build import BuildApiMixin
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 9, in 
    from .. import utils
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/**init**.py", line 2, in 
    from .utils import (
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 19, in 
    from .. import tls
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/tls.py", line 5, in 
    from .ssladapter import ssladapter
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/ssladapter/**init**.py", line 1, in 
    from .ssladapter import SSLAdapter # flake8: noqa
  File "/home/balacite/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/ssladapter/ssladapter.py", line 21, in 
    from backports.ssl_match_hostname import match_hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by :

Ansible was using python3.7

- pip3 install docker-compose==1.9.0

Answer (score 0):

can you check if docker is running?

do something like

`docker ps`

If it's not running try running pip install docker and let me know if any errors show up.

Answer (score 0):

Its running and i dont have problem  :

user@zaymaster:~$ sudo docker ps
[sudo] password for user: 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
user@zaymaster:~$